# DotNet Core support for the Ignite .Net client

Tags: ignite

I'm looking at using Ignite and the .Net client for a project.

I'm curious as to whether the client supports .Net Core so could be used in a .Net Core application.

If not, is .Net Core support planned for the future?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET Core support is planned: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-2662

Comment: Thanks Pavel. It looks like this might be a long way off though. Is that correct?

Comment: I expect this to be done this year. The change is not very complicated, and demand for this feature grows. VS 2017 comes in March, so we should finally have production-quality .NET Core tooling.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, I'll look out for it.

Comment: .NET Core Support was implemented in Apache Ignite 2.4.